Is there a way in javascript to reduce the blur of an image in steps through a loop and a variable?
I am trying something like this:
let str = 10;
let blu = "px";
let val = "";

function check() {
    if(a < b){
    str = str - 6;
    if (str<0){str = 0}
    val = str+blu;
    document.getElementById("img1").`style.filter = 'blur(val)';
}

Here the value of 'str' and hence 'val' changes everytime the function 'check' is run, but 'blur(val)' gives an error.
I was expecting that a variable can be used here. I also tried setProperty.
document.getElementById("img1").style.setProperty("blur", val);
but this also gives error.
What is the solution?
Also, how do you reduce the blur of a text or a image according to a timer. For example, if the initial blur is set to 60px, every passing second, the blur reduces by 1 px, and finally after 1 minute, entire text is clearly visible?

but 'blur(val)' gives an error. - but this also gives error.  What's the error messages?

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure to take the [tour] and learn [ask]. For people to be able to help you, you must provide a [mcve], together with sample input and output, and all the relevant information, like error messages or images/

Variables in strings are not automatically detected and replaced in JavaScript. You need to a) use template literals (backticks as string delimiters) and b) mark expressions inside those explicitly by wrapping them in ${}. Try document.getElementById("img1").style.setProperty("filter", \blur(${val})`);`.

You need add some code so that your problem is easily reproducible.

In addition to what @connexo said, you need to let the browser repaint between the iterations of the loop. This can be done either by converting the function to async and awaiting a delay (using function delay(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)) }), or by changing the loop into an indirect recursion using setTimeout with the function itself as a callback. Otherwise, the change in CSS will happen without the user being able to see its effect.

Thanks a lot @connexo, that works. Yes Amadan, I will include that too. Thanks.

Yes, but why not use a CSS transition instead? Simple and smooth.


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.i1').classList.toggle('blur')
})
.i1 {
  display: block;
  margin: 3em auto 0;
  transition: 2s;
}

.i1.blur {
  filter: blur(20px);
}
wait for image to load, then <button>toggle blur</button>
<img class="i1" src="http://picsum.photos/300/100">




Yes, I realise that this answer doesn’t directly address the question. I’m guessing there is an XY problem here.

Yes, it addresses the second part of the problem i.e the timer question. Thanks. The first part got addressed by @connexo's response.


Use template literals (backtics) in the correct place, you have a loose one in your code
Give the browser time to actually repaint
Cache the element



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // page lements are available
  let str = 60;
  let tId;
  const img = document.getElementById("img1")

  const check = () => {
    str -= 10;
    if (str < 0) {
      clearInterval(tId); // stop
      return;
    }
    let blur = `blur(${str}px)`;
    img.style.filter = blur;
    console.log(blur);
  }
  tId = setInterval(check, 1000); //loop
  check(); // run immediately
})
#img1 {
  filter: blur(100px)
}
<img id="img1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />



<img id="img1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />

Here is one where I guessed at what you wanted with a and b


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // when page elements are available
  let str = 60;
  let a=10;
  let b=0;
  let tId;
  const img = document.getElementById("img1")

  const check = () => {
    if (a < b) { // not sure what you want here, it can be deleted
      str -= 10;
      if (str < 0) {
        clearInterval(tId); // stop
        return;
      }
      let blur = `blur(${str}px)`;
      img.style.filter = blur;
      console.log(blur);
    }
    a--;
    b++;
  }
  tId = setInterval(check,1000); //loop
})
#img1 { filter: blur(100px) }
<img id="img1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />




Thanks, I will take care of points 2 and 3.
